Ignore package-lock of git dependecy on npm install
I have a UI kit dependency, which is resolved from git like this:
"dependencies": {
  "ui-kit": "git+ssh://git@***",
  ...
}

This git repo contains my lib with a package-lock.json file. When I hit npm install, it seems that npm just clones this repo and does npm install inside my dependency. The problem is that package-lock.json of this lib consists of links resolved from a nexus registry and I don't have any access to it. So I would like to download them via npmjs registry.
I expected npm to simply ignore lock files of its dependecies, but probably it won't work because of git dependency. Is there any way to override this behavior?
I wish that I could simply add package-lock file to .npmignore inside my lib, so it will be ignored during installation. But, because of dependecy resolved from git, it doesn't work as expected.
Also I can't just delete package-lock file, so it should be kept.
